Valuation of $p-1-\zeta_{p^{n}}-...-\zeta_{p^{n}}^{p-1}$
Let $\zeta_{p^n}$ be a $p^n$th root of unity in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. I want to compute the valuation of
$$p-1-\zeta_{p^{n}}-...-\zeta_{p^{n}}^{p-1}$$
We can rewrite $p-1-\zeta_{p^{n}}-...-\zeta_{p^{n}}^{p-1} \equiv \frac{\zeta_{p^n}^p-1}{\zeta_{p^n}-1} \mod p$, so
$$v_p(p-1-\zeta_{p^{n}}-...-\zeta_{p^{n}}^{p-1})= v_p(\zeta_{p^n}^p-1) - v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)$$
We have $v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)= \frac{v_p(p)}{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$.
Moreover, we have $1+\zeta_{p^n}^p-1 = \zeta_{p^n}^p = (1+ \zeta_{p^n}-1)^p \equiv 1 + (\zeta_{p^n}-1)^p$. It implies $v(\zeta_{p^n}^p-1) = v((\zeta_{p^n}-1)^p) = p \cdot v(\zeta_{p^n}-1)$.
Is it true?

For $n\ge 2$, $\zeta_{p^n}^p$ is a $p^{n-1}$-th root of unity, so your formula $v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)= \frac{v_p(p)}{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$ (by the way, isn't the numerator just $1$?) without ado implies $v_p(\zeta_{p^n}^p-1)= \frac{v_p(p)}{p^{n-2}(p-1)}$ which is of course $p \cdot v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)$. Then again, if you calculate mod $p$, from the valuation of that quotient being $p$, i.e. bigger than $v_p(p)$, you can only infer that your expression has valuation $\ge v_p(p)$.

As a quick sanity check with basic algebra, in case $n=1$, your expression is just $p$ (not just modulo $p$ but exactly) i.e. has valuation $v_p(p)$.

Ah wait, retracting the last part of my first comment: Showing that the geometric sum $1+...+\zeta_{p^n}^p$ has valuation $\infty$ (for $n=1$) or $p > 1$ (for $n\ge 2$), by virtue of the strong triangle inequality, indeed implies that $v_p(p-(\text{that sum})) = 1$.

Instead of using a special argument, we can go ahead and call $\zeta_{p^n}^p = \zeta_{p^{n-1}}$ and reuse the formula $v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)=\frac{1}{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$ to get,
$$v_p(\zeta_{p^{n-1}}-1) - v_p(\zeta_{p^n}-1)$$
$$=\frac{1}{p^{n-2}(p-1)}-\frac{1}{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{p^{n-1}}$$
Then the rest is downhill from there for the rest of the $n \ge 2$ case.
For $n=1$ it is explicitly $p-\frac{\zeta_p^p-1}{\zeta_p-1} = p$.
